# Is there C library that implement the tensor product?

Tags: c, matrix-multiplication

In *Mathematica*, I can do the tensor product calculation via the built-in `Dot[]`, for instance, here is a tensor `pts` with rank `6`:

```
SeedRandom[10];
pts = RandomReal[1, {7, 7, 7, 5, 6, 5}];

(*coeffs = {c1, c2, c3, c4}*)
coeff = BernsteinBasis[#1, Range[0, #1], #2] & @@@ 
          Thread@{(Dimensions[pts, 4] - 1), {0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4}};
(*
{{0.531441,0.354294,0.098415,0.01458,0.001215,0.000054,1.*10^-6},  
 {0.262144,0.393216,0.24576,0.08192,0.01536,0.001536,0.000064},
 {0.117649,0.302526,0.324135,0.18522,0.059535,0.010206,0.000729},
 {0.1296,0.3456,0.3456,0.1536,0.0256}}
*)

(*do tensor product calculation --->  c4.(c3.(c2.(c1.pts))) *)
Fold[#2.#1 &, pts, coeff]
```

[image]

[image]

I Google the key word `tensor product in C`, then I discovered that most tensor libraries are written in C++, rather than ANSI C.

so I would like to know:

- Is there **C** library that implements the `Dot[]` operation?

Comment: you may have to use BLAS matrix product routines such as [cblas_gemm()](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/520775) with C interface to simulate the tensor product then. It is basically redoing what those c++ tensor libs have done.

Comment: @kangshiyin Thanks for your suggestion. In fact, I need to a c library of tensor product  to  implement a `b-spline function` via the *Mathematica LibraryLink* wrapper. Please see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120384/why-does-this-librarylink-function-crash)

Comment: I'm sure it can be implement by matrix product too.

Comment: @kangshiyin Do you mean that the`tensor product` calculation could be simplified to `matrix multiplication`? If so, could you give me a demo? Thanks:) Because it is *not* easy for me to understand the  tensor product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to use BLAS matrix product routines such as [`cblas_gemm()`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/520775) with C interface to simulate the tensor product. It is basically redoing what those c++ tensor libs have done.

Your tensor product

```
c1(1x7) * pts(7x7x7x5x6x5)
```

can be seen as a matrix product

```
c1(1x7) * mat_pts(7x(7*7*5*6*5*6))
```

where `pts` is 6-D tensor, but `mat_pts` is 2-D matrix.

Thus you can use matrix product to calculate the tensor product.